# Resposta soluciona problema mas recebe -1

Tags: debate

### Entendendo o caso...

A seguinte pergunta [Adicionar e Remover campos com Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34770/adicionar-e-remover-campos-com-javascript) obteve duas respostas que *solucionariam* o problema do OP. Entretando, uma delas recebeu um voto `-1` de um usuário que simplesmente disse que *não aceitava a solução por não ser uma boa prática de programação* e, indiretamente, obrigou o outro usuário a alterar a sua resposta para que ele mudasse sua avaliação para `+1`.

Achei desnecessário essa atitude, pois o OP já havia escolhido a resposta correta, tendo em vista de que seria a melhor entre as duas a que a boa prática estava sendo aplicada.

### Questão:

Devemos dar `-1` e obrigar a edição de perguntas (*dizendo que irá mudar a avaliação para `+1` caso o faça*) que são **corretas** porém, ao ponto de vista subjetivo de outros usuários, não são? O `-1` não é aplicável apenas em respostas que não solucionam o problema ou/e que estão erradas?

<sub>**Obs.**: Não estou levando em consideração o ato do usuário de alertar o *porquê* de ter dado `-1`, mas sim o motivo deste ato.</sub>

Comment: `-1` não é reservado apenas para respostas *erradas*, mas sim para respostas **ruins**. Se alguém encontra um ponto ruim em uma resposta, mesmo que ela como um todo esteja correta, está em seu direito negativar. O resultado final disso são respostas melhores, não vejo nada de errado. (Embora eu não goste muito da noção de "pegar um `+1` de refém" até que faça a edição, é uma forma de dizer que o `-1` não foi dado para a resposta inteira, só a um ponto específico que pode ser resolvido.)

Comment: Entendo, mas acho que neste caso você 'obriga' o usuário a refazer sua resposta para não ser negativado, embora eu concorde que viriam respostas melhores, acho que há meios diferentes de obter isso, que ao invés de negativar o usuário obrigando ele a refazer a resposta, simplesmente postaria um comentário. Algo como assim: **Você poderia utilizar algo como 'tal'..., Acho que não é uma boa ideia você usar 'tal'...** ou algo parecido, alertando o usuário que respondeu de que a resposta dele tem um erro.

Comment: @biio Creio que a maioria concorda que não é agradável negativar para forçar uma edição, mas não havendo excesso, é um direito da pessoa. E ninguém é obrigado a mudar a resposta por causa disso. Se você tem confiança de que a resposta é boa, basta apenas arcar com os dois pontinhos a menos. Não é um grande prejuízo. Eu mesmo já deixei respostas negativadas aparentemente sem motivo porque acreditei que poderiam ser úteis do jeito que estava.

Comment: Todo mundo pode fazer o que quiser no site. Claro que tudo trará consequências, positivas, neutras ou negativas. Você pode desde ser ignorado até ser expulso definitivamente de acordo com o que faz no site. É impossível viver em comunidade e não aceitar consequências. Entre os extremos citados uma das coisas possíveis é receber um negativo por um post que não está sendo útil. E este é o critério básico para uso do negativo. O detalhe de como usar, é de **cada um**. Ninguém é obrigado a nada, mas pedir que uma ação não tenha consequências é... inconsequente.

Comment: "Resposta soluciona problema" Esta é a sua opinião, outra pessoa tem uma opinião diferente da sua. Por isso é que todos participam. Todos avaliam. Você deve ter votado positivamente na resposta, certo? Ele ganhou 10 ponto com seu voto. Quem negativou possivelmente está pensando a mesma coisa: "Como alguém pode votar positivamente em algo com problemas?". Quem está certo? As pessoas podem opinar mas não é fácil dar razão absoluta para um lado ou outro.

Comment: @bigown Na verdade eu não votei positivo e nem negativo, levando em consideração este "erro" na resposta "certa", o que vocês estão levando em consideração é que existem apenas 2 lados *(todo mundo é binário aqui? Rsrs)*, Positivo e Negativo, mas acredito que exista o meio-termo `0`, basta não votar e comentar o que possivelmente possa ser uma resposta correta alertando o erro na resposta, e aí, após o usuário se manifestar ou mesmo editar a resposta, acredito que sim, votaria positivo ou negativo dependendo do resultado final da questão.

Comment: Levantei esta questão pois vejo que o usuário fica obrigado a *editar* a pergunta. A justificativa de *arcar com os dois pontinhos a menos* não faz o menor sentido quando se está sendo prejudicado simplesmente por ter respondido uma pergunta corretamente, porém de jeito diferente, este é meu ponto de vista.

Comment: @biio podemos ser ternários quanto a isso, conforme eu falei no início do comentário, positivar, negativar ou ser neutro (não existe outra forma). Cada um tem seu critério de usar cada caso. Você tem o seu critério, neste caso de ser neutro, beleza. Outra pessoa tem outro. Eu por exemplo não gosto que uma pessoa saiba como votar em algo e deixa de votar. Mas é meu gosto, não posso impor para ninguém. Eu sou quem mais vota negativo e estou entre os que mais vota positivo. Não me omito, apenas me abstenho. Mas não imponho o mesmo comportamento para todo mundo.

Comment: Não entro do mérito desta questão, não saberia avaliar ao certo. Mas eu acho que a comunidade ter que arcar com um resposta "manca" pra mim é muito mais prejudicial do que a pessoa perder dois pontos. São só dois pontos. Vou repetir você está colocando a sua opinião em relação à resposta, outra pessoa pensa diferente. Você pode estar certo, mas a outra pessoa é que pode estar certa. Você pode debater o assunto sem problemas mas tem que entender que as pessoas pensam diferente. Quando há um impasse, cada um faz o que acha melhor. Você fica neutro e a outra pessoa negativa. A vida é assim.

Comment: Até porque, se a resposta for boa, os positivos vão superar os negativos, o sistema já foi feito considerando isto. Aliás, no caso em questão, o autor da resposta deixou ela melhor e não só o -1 dado foi embora, como gahou mais votos por isto.

Comment: Então eu não posso postar uma pergunta ou resposta opinativa mas posso me basear em avaliar subjetivamente uma resposta ou questão? Desculpe, isso está me confundido agora. Mas tudo bem compreendo o esclarecimento de como tratar este caso. Enquanto surgir respostas que EU achar que está errada, vou negativar, é isso?

Comment: @biio Antes de mais nada, não quero que você comece a negativar respostas usando critério de outros usuários. Por outro lado, se **você** tem motivos para considerar uma resposta **errada**, então você *pode* julgar até que ponto vai o erro. Se você notar um equívoco, pode simplesmente comentar ou ainda complementar com informação útil. Se for algo pior, negativar será um *favor* para que os próximos usuários que visitarem a página não percam tempo com a resposta. Sim, é subjetivo e, sim, depende do seu julgamento. Não vote na onda dos outros.

Comment: Tudo bem! Claro que minhas opiniões não serão mais totalmente lógicas, levarei também meu ponto de vista diante das respostas e não irei levar em consideração a avaliação das outras pessoas *(O que, afinal, todos deveriam fazer.)*. Agradeço ao pessoal. Obrigado!