# Votos negativos sem legitimidade?

Tags: debate

Acabei de receber um voto negativo na pergunta [Nome dos campos de um objeto genérico - reflection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262310/nome-dos-campos-de-um-objeto-gen%C3%A9rico-reflection) e o mais engraçado (*porque venho recebendo direto*) o outro companheiro também levou, será que o voto foi dado porque as pessoas acham que é uma pergunta duplicata e merecem voto negativos ou é perseguição, sendo que as duas respostas complementam de certa forma as duplicatas?

Fico observando muito o site e muitos usuários e existem duplicatas que são vistas até melhores do que as respostas antigas, mas, nesse caso fomos penalizados sem justificativa.

Comment: Penalizados com 1 negativo? Entendo sua frustração, é irritante mesmo receber negativo, ainda mais sem saber sua causa, mas bola pra frente.

Comment: @Articuno é uma penalidade sem justificativa, inclusive as respostas estão corretas, porque, não brigar por aquilo que agrega no site e faz diferença? Não é só um voto negativo é um exemplo de alguns.

Comment: Bom, apesar de ser uma tag que eu não participo e um assunto que não tenho conhecimento para poder votar ou julgar, posso deduzir que quem negativou provavelmente deve ter feito porque acha que responder duplicata é algo ruim. Claro que não é bem assim, nesse ponto eu concordo com seu questionamento mesmo.

Comment: @Articuno pode ser mesmo, é interessante descobrir o problema apesar de não ser fácil.

Comment: Agora é pra ficar preocupado mesmo ... complicado. a resposta do outro companheiro recebeu votos e foi editada inclusive pelo problema de digitação que tinha, como eu reforço votos sem legitimidade estão acontecendo e votos no usuários ainda reinam no pt stackoverflow, infelizmente ... !

Comment: Concordo...pra eu dar um Downvote sou muito criterioso.. comento antes vejo se a pessoa corrige o erro na resposta.. porque sei que "fere o ego" um downvote. você não foi o único Virgilio, tenho questões que tenho 6, 7 positivos e alguem vai lá e dá downvote.. de graça.. infelizmente, a propósito +1 pra vc lá, excelente resposta.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic pessoal não consegue ver quem votou? ou é secreto esse tipo de coisa?

Comment: Isso aconteceu também [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262880/pegar-peda%C3%A7o-de-texto-dentro-de-uma-palavra-javascript). No momento das "enxurradas" de respostas, uma [pessoa respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262883/5043) a pergunta e em menos de 20 segundos já foi negativada, eu "positivei" a resposta, pois ela poderia ajudar o AP, tanto que foi a "única" que ajudou. Aprenda como eu aprendi, já tive [essa discussão por aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2077/resposta-soluciona-problema-mas-recebe-1) e descobri que o voto é subjetivo.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro que eu saiba o povo é secreto e obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: @bio obrigado, mas, é um comportamento muito ruim para o site, não é pelo voto negativo, e por dar e não saber o motivo, mas, o que acabei presenciando é mais problemas de voto tipo voto no usuário e não na resposta é um comportamento que particularmente me incomoda.

Comment: Receber um ou outro voto negativo sem explicação é algo comum. Pode ser alguém que não entendeu nada da pergunta ou da resposta e acha que você está errado, pode ser algum desafeto querendo vingança por causa de algum problema passado, pode ser alguém que postou uma resposta inferior e ficou com ciúme, pode ser a ex-namorada raivosa, pode ser o vizinho que reclama que seu cachorro faz barulho... Enfim, se esses votos negativos forem esporádicos e não tiverem explicações nenhuma, nem vale a pena perder tempo esquentando a cabeça por causa deles.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro (CC VirgilioNovic) Apenas os CMs tem poder de violar o segredo do voto (atualmente o nosso CM é o JNat, até pouco tempo atrás era o Gabe), e eles só irão fazer isso se houver forte suspeita de manipulação de votos. (https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5575/132)

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim realmente... eu relatei o problema porque está virando recorrente e a minha preocupação que era uma virou duas ... a sua duplicata trata da segunda, mas, a primeira continua. O que pude perceber que o voto foi dado de qualquer forma onde a pergunta e as duas respostas receberam -1, um padrão na minha visão... mas, obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.

Comment: Eu já dei mts votos negativos "anonimamente". Mas de uns tempos pra cá eu adotei o seguinte critério de sempre deixar o motivo nos comentários. Acho que é o mais ético.

Comment: Acrescentando: quando é pergunta, a maioria das vezes eu fico no anonimato. Mas em respostas, 100% eu digo o motivo.

Answer (score 4):

Deixo aqui o que costumamos dizer aos utilizadores que nos contactam através do formulário de contacto, sobre as suas publicações terem sido votadas contra sem razão:

> Ainda que encoragemos os utilizadores a deixar um comentário construtivo quando votam contra uma publicação, isto não é um requisito. Votar é uma decisão de cada indivíduo, e é essencial para manter um sistema onde o melhor conteúdo sobe naturalmente até ao topo, tendo maior visibilidade.
>
> Ocasionalmente, alguém pode discordar de uma porção da sua publicação, achá-la de alguma maneira imperfeita ou de algum modo incorrecta, ou talvez possa achá-la demasiado difícil de ler e compreender. Quando vir um voto contra sem explicação, a melhor coisa a fazer é olhar para a sua publicação e verificar se há alguma coisa que lhe possa ter escapado:
>
> - Formatou os seus exemplos de código apropriadamente? A sua publicação tem todos os exemplos de que necessita?
> - A sua publicação é fácil de ler? Contém muitas frases muito compridas, ou erros de pontuação ou gramática?
> - Verificou que qualquer link que inclua na publicação funciona?
> - Explicou claramente como a sua resposta se relaciona com e responde à pergunta? (no caso de respostas)
>
> Ocasionalmente, as pessoas são apenas demasiado picuinhas ou carregam num botão quando queriam carregar noutro. Se voltou a verfiicar a sua publicação e não conseguem ver nada de errado com esta, então não se preocupe demasiado e não leve pessoalmente. Estamos todos aqui para aprender enquanto partilhamos o nosso conhecimento, e não devemos perder esse objectivo de vista.

É óbvio que, se detectares um padrão que parece *perseguir utilizadores e não posts*, o melhor a fazer é sinalizar uma das publicações que te parece encaixar no padrão, para que os moderadores possam investigar e/ou escalar o assunto para os CMs.

Comment: Então, eu entendi que existe um padrão, por isso do meio questionamento, não é muito normal todos receberam um voto negativo na pergunta e respostas (não que não seja válido), mas, foi dado pelo que pude observar todos ao mesmo tempo. Algo pode estar ocorrendo ou não, mas, o alerta fica como forma de observação, talvez colocar os moderadores a par do assunto aqui seja a melhor forma, para ascender um luz para observações futuras.

Comment: Mesmo levando esses pontos em questão, muitas vezes é primeiro dado um voto negativo e após feito os questionamentos. Muitas vezes explicar um problema pode ser complicado, pois entendemos o contexto do problema e os demais não. Não vejo motivo para distribuir voto negativo porque ta mal escrito sem antes pedir para o autor da pergunta deixar mais claro.